# How to I actively set JLabels from an ArrayList to the JPanel?

Tags: java, arraylist, jlabel

I am trying to make a Frogger game.

This is a simple JPanel with JLabels on it.

```
public class PlayField extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

ArrayList<JLabel> rows = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
Random g = new Random();

public PlayField(int length){  //length is the number of rows

    generateField(length);
    for(JLabel label : rows){
        add(label);  //here is where I add all of the labels to the panel
    }
}

public void generateField(int length){          //generates our JLabels in the ArrayList..

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
        int obstaclePos = g.nextInt(5);
        switch (obstaclePos){

            case 0: lbl.setText(" X — — — —");
            break;
            case 1: lbl.setText(" — X — — —");
            break;
            case 2: lbl.setText(" — — X — —");
            break;
            case 3: lbl.setText(" — — — X —");
            break;
            case 4: lbl.setText(" — — — — X");
            break;


        }

        lbl.setBounds(0,20*i,80,20);
        rows.add(lbl);  //adding the JLabels to my arraylist
        lbl.setName("row" + i);

    }

}

public void push(){  //scrolls text one to the right and puts last character at the beginning

    for(JLabel label : rows){
        label.setText(rotate(label.getText()));
    }

}

public String rotate(String str){  //cycles text one to the right, and wraps last character

    String first = str.substring(0, str.length());
    String second = str.substring(str.length());
    return second+first;

}
```

It is very difficult to exactly word my question but I basically want the JLabels that are added to the JPanel to be altered and updated when the push() function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rotate method is not right...

```
String first = str.substring(0, str.length());
String second = str.substring(str.length());
```

Should be something more like

```
String first = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
String second = str.substring(str.length() - 1);
```

`first` will be all the characters excluding the last character and `second` will be the last character.

But, remember, you have "spaces" within your `String` which may make the process a little more complicated

Comment: Wow, I  cant believe it! Yeah, I will have to run rotate() twice I think for each push(). Thank you so very much for your help

Comment: Actually just removing the spaces seemed to work out nicer than rotate() twice

Comment: That's what I was thinking ;)